# Set paths to scan for @import directives in grunt-contrib-sass

Tags: sass, grunt-contrib-sass

Grunt-contrib-less has an option `paths` that allows you to specify directories to scan with @import directives. [Here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#paths) is the option on grunt-contrib-less' doc page.

Is there something equivalent for grunt-contrib-sass? I have looked a bit but haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

[loadPath](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#loadpath)

> Add a (or multiple) Sass import path.